# Firebase schedule crontab limitations

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to schedule a Firebase cloud function to run at every 10th minute from 5 through 59 (5,15,25,35...).

5/10 * * * *

However, when I deployed my schedule it only triggered my function at minute 5 of any hour.

I think that my crontab is not supported by Firebase.

How do I implement such a crontab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Firebase crontab limitations, I had to solve my issue by giving the exact minutes I want the function to be triggered.

5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * *

Firebase do support that format.

A good use-case, to know if your cron is supportad by Firebase before deploying your function, is to validate your cron on [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/). You will be notify wether your cron is standard or not. Firebase support only standard crons.